# Implicit resolution failure when multiple instances present, despite having different types

Tags: scala, implicit

My goal is to implement a `Schema[T]` (from [scala-jsonschema](https://github.com/andyglow/scala-jsonschema)) and `Writes[T]` (from [play-json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json)) for a handful of `T` classes whose companions I can't modify. My sub-goal is to define them close together to help them stay in sync in case of refactoring.

To that end, I've created a little helper trait to pair them together, and some implicits to pull the `schema` and `writes` out implicitly

```scala
trait SchemaHelper[T] {
  def schema: Schema[T]
  def writes: Writes[T]
}

implicit def writesFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Writes[T] = c.writes
implicit def schemaFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Schema[T] = c.schema
```

The problem I'm seeing is that if I define more than one `SchemaHelper` in the current implicit search scope (even if they are different types; this isn't an ambiguous implicits problem), *none* of them work.

For example:

```scala
object MySchemas {
  implicit val stringHelper: SchemaHelper[String] = new SchemaHelper[String] {
    def schema = Schema.string
    def writes = Writes.of[String]
  }

  implicit val intHelper: SchemaHelper[Int] = new SchemaHelper[Int] {
    def schema = Schema.integer
    def writes = Writes.of[Int]
  }

  implicit val fooHelper: SchemaHelper[Foo] = new SchemaHelper[Foo] {
    // this example uses macro-generated values, but many of my
    // actual classes will not, or will build on the macro-generated result
    def schema = json.Json.schema[Foo]
    def writes = play.api.libs.json.Json.writes[Foo]
  }

  // ...and so on, but with my actual classes
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit def writesFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Writes[T] = c.writes
  implicit def schemaFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Schema[T] = c.schema

  import MySchemas._

  val exampleSchema = implicitly[Schema[Foo]] // does not work
  val exampleSchema2 = schemaFromHelper[Foo// works
}
```

In this example, `implicitly[Schema[Foo]]` does not resolve (even though IntelliJ thinks it does, and even points to `schemaFromHelper` in its implicit popup thing).

If I comment out the `stringHelper` and `intHelper`, so that `fooHelper` is the only `SchemaHelper` implicit defined in MySchemas, `implicitly[Schema[Foo]]` works again. This runs counter to my understanding of... every single type-class. I should be able to have an implicit `SchemaHelper[A]` and `SchemaHelper[B]` in scope without things falling apart.

[Example on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YPVkykVIRhyvNkqyYxgRLQ)

In my attempts to debug, I found the `-Xlog-implicits` flag, which gives me... unhelpful output:

```
[error] <redacted>\schemas.scala:17:29: implicit error;
[error] !I e: json.Schema[example.Foo]
[error] schemaFromHelper invalid because
[error] !I evidence$2: example.SchemaHelper[T]
[error]                 val exampleSchema = implicitly[Schema[Foo]]
[error]                                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

At this point I'm stumped. This seems like a compiler bug to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I did. It was posted in my question, see "Example on Scastie"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing seems to be in covariance of `Schema[T]` while `Writes[T]` and `SchemaHelper[T]` are invariant type classes.

Indeed,

```scala
trait Schema[+T]

trait Writes[+T]

trait SchemaHelper[+T] {
  def schema: Schema[T]
  def writes: Writes[T]
}

implicit def writesFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Writes[T] = c.writes
implicit def schemaFromHelper[T](implicit c: SchemaHelper[T]): Schema[T] = c.schema

case class Foo(id: Int, name: String)
implicit val intHelper: SchemaHelper[Int] = new SchemaHelper[Int] {
  def schema: Schema[Int] = ???
  def writes: Writes[Int] = ???
}
implicit val fooHelper: SchemaHelper[Foo] = new SchemaHelper[Foo] {
  def schema: Schema[Foo] = ???
  def writes: Writes[Foo] = ???
}

implicitly[SchemaHelper[Foo]]
implicitly[Writes[Foo]]
implicitly[Schema[Foo]]
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/uICRbhWvSUWrfgnZ3SHZvQ

compiles in 2.13.12 and

```scala
trait Schema[T]

trait Writes[T]

trait SchemaHelper[T] {
  def schema: Schema[T]
  def writes: Writes[T]
}

...
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/uICRbhWvSUWrfgnZ3SHZvQ/1

compiles but

```scala
trait Schema[+T]

trait Writes[T]

trait SchemaHelper[T] {
  def schema: Schema[T]
  def writes: Writes[T]
}

...
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/uICRbhWvSUWrfgnZ3SHZvQ/2

doesn't.

This is fixed in Scala 3: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/uICRbhWvSUWrfgnZ3SHZvQ/3

A workaround is to introduce an "invariant" type alias for `Schema[T]`

```scala
type Schema[T] = json.Schema[T] // NOT type Schema[+T] = json.Schema[T]
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/GBTHb10wT0iV9jK4dwg79A/3

(I'm writing "invariant" in quotes because the alias type `Schema[T]` is still covariant, `implicitly[Schema[t1] <:< Schema[t2]]` for `t1 <: t2`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/GBTHb10wT0iV9jK4dwg79A/8)